# Python Error: lxml + tidylib / I'd like to solve grabled character

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, lxml, htmltidy

everyone.
Please let me ask a following question.
I use python 2.6 and I wrote this script.
But I got an Error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cchardet, urllib2
import lxml.html
from tidylib import tidy_document

class ParseHTML(object):
    def __init__(self, html):
        self.charset = cchardet.detect(html)['encoding']
        self.html = html
        self.html = self.html.decode(self.charset) # lineA
        self.document, self.errors = tidy_document(self.html)
        self.dom = lxml.html.fromstring(self.document)
    def getTitle(self):
        self.title = self.dom.xpath('//title')[0].text
        return self.title.strip()

url = r'http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASG2B5T0ZG2BUHBI131.html?iref=comtop_6_01'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
parse = ParseHTML(html)
title = parse.getTitle()
print title
```

Then I have an Error.

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.
```

If I comment out the lineA, the script works, however, the consequence becomes garbled.
I am bothered by garbled character.
I would like to solve the problem of character with purifying by HTML Tidy.

How should I change this script?
Any advice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this is using lxml only

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> with open('out.html', 'w') as f:
...     root = etree.parse(url, etree.HTMLParser())
...     title = root.xpath('//title/text()')[0]
...     f.write(title.encode("utf-8"))
```

loading out.html in a browser shows:

```
中国・台湾、窓口役の担当閣僚が会談　４９年の分断後初：朝日新聞デジタル
```

Comment: Hi, Guy Gavriely. Thank you for your answer. Thanks to your answer, I could find what was wrong. Thank you very much.